# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 15

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to write this code to read a file and input the values as an array. Then with those values, add the numbers in the spot 1-5, 2-6,3-7, etc until the end of the file, after doing this i want to put these new values into an array.

Then i am trying to compare the array's to see if the first array value is > 0.999 bigger than the second array's value

my code is here, this is just for getting the values right, not moved on to the second part of the code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Asgn7
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {   
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("asgn7data.txt"));
        double[] array = new double[file.nextInt()];
        double[] newArray = new double[array.length];
        int counter = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int maxTemp = 0;
        int minTemp = 0;
        double tempVar = 0;
        double tempVal = 0;

        while (file.hasNextInt()) array[counter++] = file.nextInt();
        {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++)
        {   

            for (int j = 0; j < 5 ; j++)
            {
                newArray[i] += array[i + j] / 5; //Getting Average TEMP over 5 days.

            }

                System.out.println(array[i]);






        }
        }










        System.out.println("Maximum Temperature within peaks " + maxTemp );


    }

}
```

This is throwing the following error

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 15
    at Asgn7.main(Asgn7.java:25)
```

EDIT: I am not sure if my code is even correct, This is my first time working with arrays and i am seriously rusty xD.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `i < array.length - 5` because you have an inner loop that scans ahead by five. Something like,

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length - 5; i++) 
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 5 ; j++)
    {
```

**or**

```
for (int i = 0 ; i + 5 < array.length; i++) 
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 5 ; j++)
    {
```

Also, you need to add the values together to get an average.

```
for (int i = 0 ; i + 5 < array.length; i++) 
{
    int total = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 5 ; j++)
    {
        total += array[i + j];
    }
    System.out.printf("Average is: %.1f%n", total / 5);
```

Comment: Another quick question.. I have two arrays, How can i compare them? Like if array1 + the value 0.999 > array2 do something, How would i compare them?

Comment: @JonRoy this isn't really the right place to ask another question, but do you mean the sum of all values in arr1 vs. the sum arr2?